# chalice helloworld deployment issue

Tags: python, chalice

I was learning about deploying the basic helloworld app in chalice with the help of https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/chalice/latest/chalice.pdf
I get an error 
unable to parse config file .aws/config
need help in resolving the error

Comment: Please run the aws configure command and then try again...

Answer (score 2):

So I have been building a full production Chalice application and I can tell you that there isn't a lot of good documentation easy to find. I found the full documentation [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/chalice/stable/chalice.pdf).

You need to do the following:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv ~/.virtualenvs/chalice
$ source ~/.virtualenvs/chalice/bin/activate
```

Then find out what version of Python you are using:

```
$ which python3.6
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
$ virtualenv --python $(which python3.6) ~/.virtualenvs/chalice
$ source ~/.virtualenvs/chalice/bin/activate
```

Then install:

```
pip install chalice
```

Now the important part for DEPLOYING...You need to setup the config file:

```
$ mkdir ~/.aws
$ cat >> ~/.aws/config
[default]
aws_access_key_id=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE
aws_secret_access_key=YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
region=YOUR_REGION (such as us-west-2, us-west-1, etc)
```

After all that is setup, you can create your chalice project:

```
$ chalice new-project {YOUR PROJECT NAME}
```

Then you can simply deploy:

```
$ chalice deploy
```

If anyone has any questions, you can hit me up.

Comment: hi, I am having an issue when trying to deploy behind a corp proxy. Do you have any experience on that matter? https://stackoverflow.com/q/51583469/791541

Comment: I posted on your issue.